# How do I cash my stimulus check if I have lost my ID and have no bank account?

Tags: check, cash, treasury, stimulus, endorsement

I recently just moved to a new area where I know nobody, and I have no bank account set up over here yet. I have no currently valid ID: I only have a photocopy of my old expired state ID and a screenshot of my social security card (front and back) which I lost over a month ago.

I just received my stimulus check in the mail but I have no idea how to cash it.  I read you can't endorse them to someone else to cash for you without being present and having a valid ID.

How can I still cash my stimulus check? I was planning to use the stimulus money to order a new ID, but I can't order one until I can cash the check to get the money to order it.

Comment: I suspect you need to apply for a replacement ID. These processes are put in to stop fraud.

Answer (score 7):

You will need to obtain a new photo ID. You can check with your new state’s DMV office to see what the requirements are and how you can meet them. They may or may not accept the photocopies you have. You might need to obtain a new Social Security card (which you can get from the Social Security Administration) and a birth certificate, which is usually obtained from the county clerk in the place where you were born.